# The Mobius Function Proof Check

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I was wondering if my proof that the sum of the Mobius function over all divisors of a natural number greater than one is zero, is correct.

---

Denote the Mobius function as $\psi(n)$. Then we know for coprime integers $m,n$ that $\psi(mn)=\psi(m)\psi(n)$. Since this is true, if $\psi(p^k)=0$ for any prime number we know that it will be zero on all natural numbers greater than one. For every natural number greater than one has a unique prime factorization $p_1^{k_1}...p_n^{k_n}$ and since the first $n-1$ product of primes is coprime with the nth prime it follows that $\psi(n)=\psi(p_1^{k_1}...p_{n-1}^{k_{n-1}})\psi(p_n^{k_n})$. Therefore consider $\psi(p^k)$ the only divsors are $1,p,...,p^k$ but by definition $\psi(p^t)=0$ for all $2 \leq t\leq k$ and since $\psi(p)+\psi(1)=-1+1=0$ we have our proof.

---

I only ask for its verification for the proof in the text is much more elaborate so I am concerned that I am missing something obvious.

Comment: By the way, the standard symbol for the Möbius function (of n$) is $\mu(n)$

Comment: Are you sure your argument shows that $\sum_{d\mid 105}\mu(d)=0$?

Comment: You seem to have omitted a step. What you need to show is that , with $f(a)=\sum_{d|a}\psi (d),$ we have  $\gcd (a,b)=1\implies f(ab)=f(a)f(b).$

Answer (score 0):

> I only ask for its verification

Only referring to verification, I think your proof does not cover the contribution, from the sum, of terms of the form
\[ 
\mu(p_{n_{1}} p_{n_{2}} \cdots p_{n_{r}}) = (-1)^{r},
\quad p_{n_{1}} \cdots p_{n_{r}} | n.
\]

Remember that $\mu(n)$ is not zero for $n$ squarefree.

Summing up these are actually not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n)=\sum_{d|n}\psi (d).$ Let $D(n)$ be the set of divisors of $n.$

Suppose $\gcd (a,b)=1.$  Then:

(i)...If $y\in D(a)$ and $z\in D(b)$ then $\gcd(y,z)=1.$

(ii)...  $x\in D(ab)$ iff there exist $y\in D(a)$ and $z\in D(b)$ with $x=yz.$

(iii)...   If $y,y'\in D(a)$ and $z,z'\in D_b$ then $yz=y'z'$ iff $(y=y'$ and $z=z')$.

$$\text { Now }\quad f(a)f(b)=\sum_{y\in D(a)}\sum_{z\in D(b)}\phi(y)\phi(z)=\sum_{y\in D(a)}\sum_{z\in D(b)}\phi(yz),$$  and every member of $D(ab)$ appears exactly once as $yz$ in the far RHS above, so the far RHS above is equal to $f(ab).$  That is, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $f(a)f(b)=f(ab).$ This is the missing part of your proof.

Now if $a>1$ and $ p$ is a prime divisor of $a$, with $\;p^k|a$, and $\;p^{k+1}\not |\; a\;$, then $k \geq 1$ and  $\gcd(a,ap^{-k})=1$. So $f(a)=f(p^k)f(ap^{-k})=0\cdot f(ap^{-k})=0.$